# mottie tablesorter hide filter row permanently

Tags: tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter 2.17.4 with the filter widget and setting filters programmatically with .setFilters

I know that widgetOptions filter_hideFilters: true allows you to hide the filter row unless you mouseover it but I'd like to hide it all the time. As it stands as soon as you apply a filter it shows. setting its css to display:none does not help as this is being overridden by the code.
Is there a config option anywhere to control this?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option you want is [`filter_columnFilters`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-columnFilters), set that to `false` and the filter row will not be added:

```
$(function(){
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
      filter_columnFilters : false
    }
  });
});
```